# What is the difference between 護る and 守る?

Tags: word-choice, homophonic-kanji

Is there any difference in meaning between 護{まも}る and 守{まも}る? When there are multiple kanji for a particular reading (like 暑{あつ}い/熱{あつ}い or 初{はじ}め/始{はじ}め), they are frequently used in different situations (hot weather/hot to touch or first time/start). According to the dictionaries (jisho.org and a pocket dictionary) 守{まも}る is more common, but the story I'm reading now is using 護{まも}る. So I was wondering if there would be any particular reason for using 護 over 守.

Comment: 守護天使 is a good mix of both.

Comment: This looks like a case of either a) a word that be written with a choice of kanji that alters the nuance, or b) two homonyms / homophones - different words that coincidentally have the same pronunciation. You might want to add the "kanji choice" or "homonyms" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically 守る is the more general and common word for "protecting, guarding, or keeping someone / something."

The 訓読み 「[護る]{まもる}」 is not listed in 常用漢字表 (thus it's not taught in schools), and it can be only specifically used to protect/guard something from foreign attacks.

- 約束{やくそく｝を守る (*keep a promise*): Good
- 約束を護る: Not good
- 秘密{ひみつ}を守る (*keep a secret*): Good
- 秘密を護る: Not good
- 法律｛ほうりつ｝を守る (*uphold/obey the law*): Good
- 法律を護る: Not good, or maybe OK if you mean "to protect the law itself from being altered badly"
- 祖国{そこく}を守る/護る (*protect the homeland*): OK
- 打撃{だげき}から身{み}を守る/護る (*protect oneself from damage*): OK
- サッカーのゴールを守る/護る (*guard the goal*): OK

Personally, I always use 守る for all those purposes, and regard 護る as the word only for novelists or songwriters.

Answer (score 5):

護る is used more to guard someone. There's  a sense of security and guarding. Instances of this can be seen in words like 護衛、援護、擁護、警護 etc

A use of 護る can be in a sentence like   陛下を護る、主君を護る

守る is used to defend or protect something. Words that use 守 include those like 守備、攻守, 守衛

Uses of 守る: 宝を守る、陣地を守る、城を守る etc.

So one's used to guard, the other is used to protect
Hope that helps

Comment: What is the difference between "guard" and "protect"?

Comment: To guard, is to watch over, and protect, if needed. So you're preparing for a "threat" which may or maynot harm your subject.
To protect/defend something, is to directly prevent it from the immediate threat.

I'll use a castle as my example.
One that "Guards・護る" a castle, is there to respond to a potential threat that pops-up. So normally, there isn't a threat, but if there is, they're there to deal with it. One that "Defends/Protects 守る", is responding to a threat that is currently occurring. 
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

My personal feeling...

The most often use of 「護」 of 「護る」 is when god defends somebody.
We use 「神の御加護がありますように」 as "I hope god bless you". And their is a 「護国神社」 in every prefecture.

Or parents defends their kids, we call 「保護者」, adults who are legally responsible for kids.