# What's with all the possible kanji for とる?

Tags: words, nuances, kanji, homophonic-kanji

Skimming through the options my IME presents for とる, I'm seeing a whole lot of choices, including the following:

- 取る
- 撮る
- 録る
- 執る
- 摂る
- 捕る
- 獲る
- 穫る
- 採る
- 盗る

While I've seen 取る ("to take") and 撮る ("to record") relatively frequently, the rest appear rather foreign to me.  What do they mean, and how are they used?

Comment: From most to least frequent on [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/): 取る (85.95%), 撮る (7.02%), 採る (2.06%), 捕る (1.51%), 奪る (0.94%), 摂る (0.86%), 執る (0.62%), 獲る (0.56%), 盗る (0.28%), 録る (0.14%), 穫る (0.06%).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already know the dictionary meanings.

- All of these とる variants listed here are understood by most Japanese adults.
- In general, using certain uncommon [同訓異字](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E8%A8%93%E7%95%B0%E5%AD%97) verbs, such as 啼く (vs 鳴く), [護る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16155/) (vs 守る), 淹れる (vs 入れる), can sometimes do more harm than good in daily practice. It's unnecessarily difficult and too poetic. You probably know this risk.
- However, [NHK does use many of these とる variants](http://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/uraomote/111.html) according to the situation, except for 穫る, 録る. Unfortunately, you can't just stick to 取る.
- 撮る is definitely worth memorizing because it's used very frequently and 「写真を取る」「映画を取る」 is 100% incorrect. However 「撮る is safe for anything involving recording」 is also not accurate because 撮る can be used only for recording *with cameras*.

  - テレビで放送されていた映画をDVDに撮る  => weird
  - 野鳥の鳴き声をスマホで撮る => weird
- Besides 取る and 撮る, **the safest strategy is not to stick to 取る, but to stick to hiragana とる**. Or you can avoid ambiguous とる altogether and use equivalents such as 盗む, 採用する, 採取する, 録画する/録音する, 捕まえる and 収穫する. These are actually what I do in daily practice. I sometimes dare write 「栄養をとる」「山菜をとる」「筆をとる」 instead of 「栄養を摂る」「山菜を採る」「筆を執る」 to make my text look milder.
- 「映画を録る (at home) 」 is not listed in 常用漢字表 but I really see this often.

Answer (score 3):

*Information primarily sourced from 大辞林's entry on とる.*

### とる

**General meaning:** to take, to manipulate; to record

### 取る

取る means “to have in hand”, “to take in hand”, “to collect”, “to demand time or labor”, “to undertake”.

Unlike 持つ【もつ】, 取る involves manipulation of the object in hand for a purpose; not just simply holding it.

### 撮る

撮る means “to shoot pictures or movies”.

### 録る

録る means “to record sound/video to a medium”.  It differs from 撮る in that it focuses on the medium moreso than the recording of what is taking place.

### 執る

執る means “to take into hand and use”, “to carry out”.

とる is often written as 取る, however it can also be written as 執る in cases such as the following:

- 筆を執る [to pick up a writing brush/to take up the pen]
- 事務を執る [to attend to business]

### 摂る

摂る means “to take into the body” (e.g. nutrition), “to eat”.

### 捕る

捕る means “to arrest”, “to catch”. (cf. 捕まる【つかまる】)

### 獲る

獲る means “to catch game” (e.g. hunting or fishing).  It can also be written as 捕る【とる】.

### 穫る

穫る means “to harvest crops”.

### 採る

採る means “to gather”, “to go hunting for”, “to collect”, “to select”.

### 盗る

盗る means “to take someone else’s things”, “to steal”.  It can also be written as 取る.

### I just want to play it safe, which ones are generic?

取る is a safe bet for most things that involve picking up or taking objects, while 撮る is safe for anything involving recording.